# Nhibernate / Propose mapped property and id

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

For filtering purpose, I'd like to propose in nhibernate both the mapped property and the id.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="BusinessObjets.ItemShopping,BusinessObjets" table="ADN_Monture" lazy="true">
     <many-to-one name="Manufacturer" column="IDManufacturer" cascade="save-update" not-null="true" />
<property name="IDManufacturer" column="IDManufacturer" type="int" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

In this case, it would propose either a Manufacturer property of the Manufacturer Type and a IDManufacturer (int).
The int would be a readonly property and would only be used to filter the data.
For example :

```
var result = from item in session.Query<ItemShopping>() select item).ToList<ItemShopping();
```

and then filter the result with linq to objects with an id.
Is there any drawback in the nhibernate process (insert / update) ?

Regards

**Edit**

Well after installing nhibernate profiler, I notice that a filter based only on the foreign key (item.Manufacturer.IdManufacturer) doesn't use the proxy. So there is no performance problem.
Can someone confirm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can experience problems in saving/updating the entity. In this case just put `update="false"` on the additional Id property, and it should work like a charm. No problem if you are just querying. BTW you should not have performance issues even if you query for the many to one. NH known to issue a query based on the Id and does not eagerly fetch anything just for issuing the query.